# How to fix the alignment issue caused by tilde/diacritics

Tags: python-3.x

```
a ="Angst"  
b ="Bónañas"
c = "Fname"
print (f'{a:<20}{c}')
print (f'{b:<20}{c}')
```

The output is funny because the two tildes/diacritics are counted as 2 string as well.

[image]

I know I can make the following modification.

```
print (f'{a:<20}{c}')
print (f'{b:<22}{c}')
```

However, is there a another way (should be suitable to use in a loop) to fix the problem ?

Comment: Why are you using the variants with diacritics as an extra char? Those letters are available as single unicode characters. Juste paste `'Bónañas'` and it will work. See https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f1/index.htm and https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f3/index.htm.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution works. It also worked when I typed the word Bónañas by myself. May you please explain the origin of this phenomenon? I could not understand this comment "Why are you using the variants with diacritics as an extra char?".

Comment: maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) helps. basically, one character that you read (e.g. n with a tilde) can be composed of two characters from the machine's perspective. That's why you got unexpected results from your f-strings.

Comment: @PythonNewbie If you check e.g. `b[1]` and `b[2]` with your original version, you will see that the first is a common `o` and the scond is the diacritic "acute". Some, not all, fonts know they are supposed to left-shift the "acute" into/over the preceding character, creating the impression of a single glyph. Since one wants to, in theory, be able to apply the "acute" to any letter one pleases, this is more efficient than to have an acute version of every unicode char. But for the common vowels, there is always a straightforward single char version with an acute on top. I am babbling :D